# Convert column in SQL database from KB to MB

Tags: sql

Asked around but no answers, hence the question here.

I've a SQL table with Column 'Length'.

This is file sizes expressed as KB. I'm trying to convert the entire column to MB and then produce a report of those that are between particular sizes.

Apologies for being dumb, but I just can't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: so are you asking how to handle changing the data or????  give more details.. what have tried?  issues??

Comment: You didn't try anything yet, did you?

Comment: Barranka answered, but essentially I'm trying to group file sizes and as they're expressed in KB I'm left with a gazillion records that are like 0.45MB. Having a report that says there are x number of files that are 0-2MB and x number of files larger than this (with this total size), will make my life a lot easier :)

Comment: And yes tried pretty much everything I could find across Google and the knowledge across the office (limited I know lol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide the value by 1024:

```
select a.*, length / 1024 as length_mb
from yourTable as a
where (length / 1024) between value1 and value2
```

You can, of course, round the value using `round()` if you need to.

---

Rounding values:

```
select a.*, round(length / 1024, 2) as length_mb
from yourTable as a
where round(length / 1024, 2) between value1 and value2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, sorry for being so dumb! Where would I insert round()?

Comment: Check updated answer (by the way, if it was useful, upvote it and/or accept it)